# Can not convert form "char*" to "char"

Tags: c++, c, string

```
char* fun(char* str)
{
    int i=0,j=1,k=0,count=1;

    if(str  == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    while(str[i] != '\0')
    {
        j=i+1;
        if(str[i] == str[j])
        {
            i++;
            j++;
            count++;
            continue;
        }
    // showing error
        str[k] = str[i];   // here its showing error at run time "can`t convert from char* to "char,
        i++;
        k++;
        if(count>1)
        {
            str[k]= count;
            k++;
        }
    }
    str[k] = '\0';
    return str;`returning str value`
}
```

please help me to find solution by giving your valuable suggestion.

`str[k] = str[i];`

// here its showing error at run time "can`t convert from `char*` to `char`",

i want to get rid of this error.

Comment: Why you have tagged it as java?

Comment: @RahulTripathi Because he needs a cup of coffee, obviously :)

Comment: str[i] and str[k] both are character. Your warning is coming from somewhere else. please try using some debuggur.

Comment: No, it isn't showing that error for that code (and it would be at compile time if it were). Post your actual code.

Answer (score 4):

I just compiled and tested your code, and I'm not getting an error. I also don't think that line should cause the error you're describing.

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing.  Consider your test independently confirmed.